# Icon representing VAT number

Tags: icons, financial

What icon would you use to represent the VAT number of an EU company? That is, one that would fit nicely with @ for e-mail, map for physical address, etc., for example on a contact page.

Comment: Well, as we are talking tax, I guess the most appropriate icon would be a criminal of some sort.

Comment: Also, icon suggestions are off-topic for this site. Please refer to [help] for more information about what you can and cannot ask.

Answer (score 2):

If the language of the page is English, then I'd just use the 3 letters VAT.  If you localise the page then you will need the acronym which relates to each language.

Comment: I'd agree with this one. VAT itself is a pretty complicated and context depends on the case. So, making users solve an 16px hieroglyph, just use VAT letters as an icon for the sake of users.

Answer (score 0):

An icon for VAT that does not include the words VAT in it won't be easy to recognize. Given this you can just use the words VAT or some type of paper with a VAT inscript on it.